# Slide down Jerky on IE and edge?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, microsoft-edge, velocity.js

This is a simple code where I'm making a slide down on a hidden div triggered when the user is pushing a button. For the slide down I'm using .velocity() instead of .animate() but it does not solve anything.

The problem occurs only on IE and Edge but is a little bit jerky in Firefox too ( no problem in chrome only), you can see the animation [here](http://www.doctirank.com)

Is it possible to fix the code and make it smooth in all browsers ? if not, do you have any turn around to make the same task ?

Comment: Animation in JS is always susceptible to not being smooth as it's not hardware accelerated. IE is even worse as it's JS engine is, frankly, terrible. An alternative is use CSS to perform your animation, however we can't really help you with that as you've not shown what logic your code is using.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made the JS fiddle here :https://jsfiddle.net/4ocfv4gL/5/